# Help me finding the surface of part of a circle which is located between two straights

Tags: integration

Find the area of part of the circle $x^2+y^2=4$ which is located between the straight lines $y=x$ and $y=2x$.

Comment: Have you found the points of intersection?

Comment: @user137500 yes they are $\sqrt{2}$ and $\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}$

Comment: Ok, are you trying to find the area of that segment? If so, integrate in polar coordinates. What you are finding is a "double" circular sector.

Comment: Is it okay if I do it in polar mode?

Comment: @user137500 yes i'm trying to find the area of the segment by integrals

Comment: Integrate $r=2$ with the polar integration formula. Find the bounds for theta by finding the angles at which the two lines cut the circle (I believe it will be $\theta=\pi/4$ and $\theta=\atan(2)$ using the formula $\tan(\theta)=m$ for lines $y=mx$.

Comment: @user137500 it should be $\theta=\pi/4$ and $\arctan(2)$

Comment: @Sabyasachi Thank you I changed the mistake.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

The reality is, you don't even need an integral here. If you recall, the area of a sector is: $$\frac{1}{2}r^2\theta$$

Now, we know what $r^2$ is (it's $4$, from the circle's equation). Now we need $\theta$. $\theta$ will be the difference in angles between the angle that $y=2x$ makes and that that $y=x$ makes ($y=2x$ is above $y=x$).

To find it, we can just use trig. We find the intersection point and, from the intersection point, we can draw a triangle.

$y=2x$ intersects at $\big(\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}, \frac{4}{\sqrt{5}}\big)$ The angle of this will be $\tan^{-1}\big(\frac{\frac{4}{\sqrt5}}{\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}}\big)=\tan^{-1}(2).$

$y=x$ intersects at $(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2})$. Hence, this is a 45-45-90 triangle and we know that $\theta$ is $\frac{\pi}{4}$ degrees.

The angle swept is then $\tan^{-1}(2)-\frac{\pi}{4}$, making the area $2\tan^{-1}(2)-\frac{\pi}{2}$.

If you also want the area on the bottom-left, just multiply that^ value by $2$.

Comment: this has a mistake. $\theta$ *must* be in radians in $\frac{1}{2}r^2\theta$

Comment: @Sabyasachi Fixed!

Answer (score 1):

The question here is a little ambiguous. The lines $y=x$ and $y=2x$ cut off two sectors of the unit circle, in the $1^{st}$ and $3^{rd}$ quadrants. If it is asking for both the areas, the answer will be double of what I am presenting.

A sector subtending an angle of $\theta$ at the centre, has $$A=\frac{ \pi r^2\theta}{2\pi}= \frac{r^2\theta}{2}$$

Here $r^2=4$ and $\theta=\arctan(2) - \pi/4$

$$\therefore A = 2\arctan(2)-\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Using Double integration and polar coordinates:

$$A=\int\int_R \rho d \rho d \theta, $$
where $R$ is the desired region. Then, as the radius varies of $\rho=0$ to $\rho=2$ and the angle $\theta$ of $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}$ to $\theta =\arctan 2$, we obtain
$$A=\int_{\rho=1}^{\rho=2}\int_{\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\theta =\arctan 2}\rho d\rho d\theta= \left(\int_{0}^2 d\theta\right)\left( \int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\arctan 2}\rho d\rho \right)=$$
$$=(\arctan 2-\frac{\pi}{4})(\frac{4}{2}-0)=2(\arctan 2-\frac{\pi}{4}). $$